# Getting the selected value out of a SDMultiWheel control

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have implemented a SDMultiWheel in my Android app.
I use the ControlValueChanged event to get the newly selected value, something like this:

```
Event &var2.ControlValueChanged  //var2 being the wheelcontrol
    msg(&var2)
Endevent
```

What's strange is that the msg returns, not the selected value, but the old one (value before the selection).

How can I get the new selected value?

Comment: That should work. The string should be the same json as before, but with the "Value" property updated. What version are you testing this on?

Comment: Yes, i get a Json string, but with the previous value (if I change from 2 to 3 - string will have the value 2). I am using Ev3 U2 (10.3.87166).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uWk845X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. I could not reproduce the problem because this issue is already fixed it our codebase. Both the Wheel and Multiwheel controls were reporting the old value when firing the `ControlValueChanged` event.

The fix will be released as part of GX Evolution 3 Upgrade 3, there are nightly builds available [here](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,8,77,O,E,0,,4691;17;4) if you want to try it.

If necessary, you should be able to backport the fix to U2. The changed files are:

```
WheelsLib/src/com/artech/controls/wheel/GxMultiWheelPicker.java
WheelsLib/src/com/artech/controls/wheel/GxWheelControl.java
WheelsLib/src/com/artech/controls/wheel/measures/GxMeasuresControl.java
```